# Sum query for MySQL where field contain certain values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need help with a Query, i have a table like this:

```
| ID  | codehwos    |
| --- | ----------- |
| 1   | 16,17,15,26 |
| 2   | 15,32,12,23 |
| 3   | 53,15,21,26 |
```

I need an outpout like this:

```
| codehwos | number_of_this_code    |
| -------- | ---------------------- |
| 15       | 3                      |
| 17       | 1                      |
| 26       | 2                      |
```

I want to sum all the time a code is used in a row.

Can anyone make a query for doing it for all the code in one time?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very poor data format.  You should not store lists in strings and never store lists of numbers in strings.  SQL has a great data structure for storing lists.  Hint:  it is called a "table" not a "string".

That said, sometimes one is stuck with other people's really poor design choices.  We wouldn't make them ourselves, but we still need to get something done.  Assuming you have a list of codes, you can do what you want with:

```
select c.code, count(*)
from codes c join
     table t
     on find_in_set(c.code, t.codehwos) > 0
group by c.code;
```

If you have any influence over the data structure, then advocate for a junction table, the right way to store this data in a relational database.

Comment: Work like a charm, thanks.
This poor table is from a WebApp who I'm developing, I'll implement a better data format in future version.
Thanks Again